# How can I combine multiple onEdit/Trigger Scripts in a Google Sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, eventtrigger

Forgive me if my wording is off, I'm new to Scripts, but someone made me a script to run onEdit/Triggers for a sheet I have. I also have an onEdit script for a date/timestamp. I had them all working briefly yesterday, but then the new onEdit trigger scripts started failing; stating I had too many scripts. The ranges that are being imported upon the triggers have formulas and conditional formatting. The cell that's triggering the events for the Stage 1, Stage 2, Stage 3, and PIT codes is a data validation cell. The sheet link and codes are at the bottom of this post.

So what I'm wondering is:

1. How to combine four(4) scripts into one(1) script, and
2. If it's possible to add coding to the script to delete the range cells it imports before it places the new triggered cells. Because each range it imports has conditional formatting that lingers after the new range is triggered.

**Sheet link:** https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KYSiVggIm7KIKxpJMnUhldrzsIaETCqyjOWJ1a9k1cI/edit?usp=sharing

**Date/Timestamp Code:**

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sheetNameFellowshipTracking = 'Fellowship Tracking';
  const dateCol = 43;

  // Get edited sheet.
  const range = e.range;
  const sheet = range.getSheet();

  if (sheet.getName() === sheetNameFellowshipTracking)
  {
    // Get edited row.
    const row = range.getRow();

    if (row >= 4 && row <= 28)
    {
      // Get current time.
      const time = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT-05:00", "MM/dd, HH:mm");

      // Set edited datetime.
      const dateModifiedRange = sheet.getRange(row, dateCol);
      dateModifiedRange.setValue(time);
    }
  }
}
```

**Stage 1 Code:**

```
function onMyEdit(e) {
  var sh=e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName()!='Fellowship Tracking')return;
  if(e.range.columnStart==7 && e.range.rowStart==31 && e.value=='Stage 1') {
    var srcrg=e.source.getSheetByName('ALL Stages+Pit').getRange('B3:G21');
    var desrg=sh.getRange('C33');
    srcrg.copyTo(desrg);
  }
}

function createOnMyEditTrigger() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('onMyEdit').forSpreadsheet(ss.getId()).onEdit().create();
}
```

**Stage 2 Code:**

```
function onMyEdit(e) {
  var sh=e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName()!='Fellowship Tracking')return;
  if(e.range.columnStart==7 && e.range.rowStart==31 && e.value=='Stage 2') {
    var srcrg=e.source.getSheetByName('ALL Stages+Pit').getRange('H3:M21');
    var desrg=sh.getRange('C33');
    srcrg.copyTo(desrg);
  }
}

function createOnMyEditTrigger() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('onMyEdit').forSpreadsheet(ss.getId()).onEdit().create();
}
```

**Stage 3 Code:**

```
function onMyEdit(e) {
  var sh=e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName()!='Fellowship Tracking')return;
  if(e.range.columnStart==7 && e.range.rowStart==31 && e.value=='Stage 3') {
    var srcrg=e.source.getSheetByName('ALL Stages+Pit').getRange('N3:S21');
    var desrg=sh.getRange('C33');
    srcrg.copyTo(desrg);
  }
}

function createOnMyEditTrigger() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('onMyEdit').forSpreadsheet(ss.getId()).onEdit().create();
}
```

**PIT Code:**

```
function onMyEdit(e) {
  var sh=e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName()!='Fellowship Tracking')return;
  if(e.range.columnStart==7 && e.range.rowStart==31 && e.value=='PIT') {
    var srcrg=e.source.getSheetByName('PIT Sheet').getRange('B5:F17');
    var desrg=sh.getRange('C33');
    srcrg.copyTo(desrg);
  }
}

function createOnMyEditTrigger() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('onMyEdit').forSpreadsheet(ss.getId()).onEdit().create();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function onMyEdit(e) { 
  const sh=range.getSheet();
  if(sheet.getName()=="Fellowship Tracking" && e.range.rowStart>=4 && e.range.rowStart<=28) {
     const time=Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT-05:00", "MM/dd, HH:mm");
     sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,43).setValue(time);
  }
  if(sh.getName()=='Fellowship Tracking' && e.range.columnStart==7 && e.range.rowStart==31 && e.value=='Stage 1') {
    const srcrg=e.source.getSheetByName('ALL Stages+Pit').getRange('B3:G21');
    const desrg=sh.getRange('C33');
    srcrg.copyTo(desrg);
  }
  if(sh.getName()=='Fellowship Tracking' && e.range.columnStart==7 && e.range.rowStart==31 && e.value=='Stage 2') {
    const srcrg=e.source.getSheetByName('ALL Stages+Pit').getRange('H3:M21');
    const desrg=sh.getRange('C33');
    srcrg.copyTo(desrg);
  }
  if(sh.getName()=='Fellowship Tracking' &&  e.range.columnStart==7 && e.range.rowStart==31 && e.value=='Stage 3') {
    const srcrg=e.source.getSheetByName('ALL Stages+Pit').getRange('N3:S21');
    const desrg=sh.getRange('C33');
    srcrg.copyTo(desrg);
  }
  if(sh.getName()=='Fellowship Tracking' && e.range.columnStart==7 && e.range.rowStart==31 && e.value=='PIT') {
    const srcrg=e.source.getSheetByName('PIT Sheet').getRange('B5:F17');
    const desrg=sh.getRange('C33');
    srcrg.copyTo(desrg);
  }
}
```

The more complicated trigger creation function.

```
   function createTrigger() {
  //guarantees that you dont create a trigger for a function if there already is one.
  if(!isTrigger('onMyEdit')) {
    ScriptApp.newTrigger('onMyEdit').forSpreadsheet(SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getId()).onEdit().create();
  }
}

function isTrigger(funcName){
  var r=false;
  if(funcName){
    var allTriggers=ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
    for(var i=0;i<allTriggers.length;i++){
      if(funcName==allTriggers[i].getHandlerFunction()){
        r=true;
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  return r;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! You're amazing once again! I used the code above, but when I run the script in the script editor it fails saying "ReferenceError: range is not defined (line 2, file "code")". So I'm guessing because it's error-ing that it's not triggering the timestamp or the G31 codes to work. Any ideas on how to fix it? Or am I possibly doing something wrong?

Comment: You need to create an installable trigger. Also these type of  functions cannot be run from the Script Editor as they need an onedit trigger event block.  That's what the e is for.

Comment: Gotcha, makes sense 'cause the timestamp code alone wouldn't run in the editor. How do I create an installable trigger?

Comment: Okay, I see the script you did yesterday that you put:
function createOnMyEditTrigger() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('onMyEdit').forSpreadsheet(ss.getId()).onEdit().create();
}

But when I put that into the script, it gives me the error "Exception: This script has too many triggers. Triggers must be deleted from the script before more can be added. (line 31, file "code")"

Comment: It would probably be better if I hadn't even given you that script.  Just go to the Script Editor Edit/Current Project Triggers and delete all of the onMyEdit() triggers and then create one of them yourself and then you will know how and don't use that script when I use those type of scripts I add some code to make sure that there aren't already triggers with the same name.  But it adds extra complication to the code so I don't always include for answers to questions in an effort to make it as easy as possible.   But yeah that's a problem.